# How i get parameters in Dialogflow response

Tags: node.js, api, dialogflow-es

i am having problems with dialogflow, i'm trying to get required parameters from dialogflow, but i can't get it.

My dialogflow content is like that

[Dialogflow intent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCN3J.png)

I'm using Node JS to connect to dialogflow with Service Account Credentials, it's not dialogflow webhook or fulfillment.

My dialogflow get it when use this phrase.

[Dialogflow getting parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0vlO.png)

This is Node JS trying to getting "$name" parameters with same phrase, returning undefined.

```
async function create(req){
    const message = "Meu nome é Renato"
    const resultado = await dialogflow.GetIntent(dialogFlowProjectID , message).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.parameters['name'])
        return res
    })
}
```

This "res" have all response from dialogflow with intent, actions ..., but this "res.parameters['name'])" is wrong, its returning undefined, i don't know if its the way to get this parameters, can you guys help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your question to show which library you're using and exactly how the `dialogflow` object is created? It may also help to see how you're calling `create()` and where the `req` object comes from. The more information you can provide, the better our chances are of helping.